# angular2 - jQuery add pixels to position top

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular

I want to position my markers when zoom 18 += 10px up, so what I dit is this:

```
  his._mapsWrapper.subscribeToMapEvent<void>('zoom_changed').subscribe(() => {
      this._mapsWrapper.getZoom().then((z: number) => {
     this._zoom = z;

     if(z === 18) {
        $('.marker').css({ 'width' : '25px', 'height' : '25px', 'line-height': '25px', 'top' : '+= 10!important' });
        $('.number-id').css({'font-size': '11px'})
     }
```

But it seems not to work can somebody help me out here? Here is a [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/4BoZyeMqRfbLuOCW8ZXG?p=preview), where you can see this code in src/google-maps/directive/google-map.ts in the method _handleMapZoomChange()

What it does it is setting all the elements to 10px, but what I basically wants is to set the current top position + 10px.

```
 $('.marker').each( function (index) {
     console.log(index + ":" + $(this).css('top'));
     var currentTop = $(this).css('top');

     $(this).css('top', currentTop + '10px');
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using custom overlay, it can cause unexpected behaviour if you adjust `left` or `top` position of the marker, because that is tied to `latLng` position of the marker.

Instead, just use `margin-top` css attribute (`margin-top: 10px` or `margin-top: -10px` depending on your needs)

The same thing when drawing the marker, don't adjust position like this:

```
if (point) {
    div.style.left = (point.x - 10) + 'px';
    div.style.top = (point.y - 10) + 'px'; 
}
```

Instead add the offset as margin-top and margin-left to your marker's css:

```
div.style.cssText = `width: 25px; 
                     height: 25px; 
                     ...
                     margin-top: -10px;
                     margin-left: -10px;`
```

Comment: But how do i know the different zoom levels in the custom overlay class?

Comment: I have answered that in the second question of yours. But please don't create multiple similar questions like this and than ask for solutions to different questions. In this question you never mentioned that you don't already have `z` set.